# Docusign: Incorrect permissions requested

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to obtain Admin consent for external application.
So I prepared link for an administrator of another company. Here is a [link](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=openid&client_id=842a1471-7f77-4b2b-8485-f67a60958f2e&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com&admin_consent_scope=signature%20impersonation)
As you can see:

```
scope=openid 
admin_consent_scope=signature%20impersonation
```

But when administrator of target organization loggining in - he see the following screen
[image: permissions]

As you can see - it is requesting only "Obtain user information". But I expected to see permissions as in documetation:
[image]

After administrator clicked "Accept" - my app still gets an error consent_required when it generates JWT token.

Comment: so the latter is organization consent, the former is user consent. You have to do more to use organization consent. You have to have an organization set up for example. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: which documentation did you follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, had a call with Docusign support. They have a bit outdated [specs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent#admin-consent-for-external-applications).
The link should not have admin_consent_scope parameter and all scopes must be in scope parameter. Got it working.